# Deleting entries from array in different documents ids using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a project Schema like this

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
type: String,
required: true,
minlength: 2,
maxlength: 50
},
box: { 
type: [String],
required: false,
minlength: 0,
maxlength: 255
},

isActive: Boolean
});
```

And I need to delete the entry of olibox from different documents

For example:

If I have 4 different `projectSchema` IDs and I want to delete 2 specific `olibox` IDs from these 4 projectSchemas..how can i dot that?

For one single document I am doing like this to delete one array element..

```
project= await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.project._id,{$pull :  {'box': req.params.oliId}},{new :true});


console.log("In post");
```

Can I use `$in` with it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see if this works. I am hoping it does.

```
Project.updateMany(
  {
    _id: { $in: ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'] }
  },
  { $pull: { box: { $in: [8025, 7323] } } }
);
```